# How to check if input is not empty on load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a code like this:

```
<div><input type="text" value=""></div>
```

How do I check with JS or jQuery if input contain any data (even from localstorage or browser cache) on load and add class to parent div if not empty?

Comment: Reading the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) is always useful.

Comment: there is no direct connection between localStorage and an `<input>` element

Comment: Thanks, I'm just not very experienced in JS, that's why asked for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
//trim() is used to remove extra spaces in your input value
if($('#ver_input').val().trim() != ''){
    $(this).parent().addClass('any-class');
}
```

html:

```
<div><input type="text" value="" id="ver_input"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

To check if the value of an input is not empty, use the following:

`if($("input").val())
{
  ...
}`

If there are multiple inputs you may want to put an id on this input, but this code works if there is just one input.

Answer (score 1):

```
  var input = document.querySelector('input');
  var yourDiv = document.querySelector('div');


  if(input.value === ''){
    yourDiv.classList.add("foo");
  }
```